# Schedule data in database transformation

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, sql-server-2016

I have the following table in sql it shows when employee has checked in at work and when they've checked out:

```
ID  Name Surname CheckInTime        CheckOutTime
123 John Johnson 2019-07-05 12:30   2019-07-05 15:30 
123 John Johnson 2019-07-06 11:30   2019-07-06 14:30
124 Paul Johnson 2019-07-01 11:30   2019-07-01 12:30
124 Paul Johnson 2019-07-02 11:30   2019-07-01 12:30
```

I want to do a report that would show on what day worker checked in / out in the following format :

```
ID Name Surname Time_type 2019-07-01 2019-07-02 2019-07-03 2019-07-04 2019-07-05 2019-07-06 ... 2019-07-31
123 John Johnson CheckInTime                                            12:30     11:30     
123 John Johnson CheckOutTime                                           15:30     14:30    
124 Paul Johnson CheckInTime 11:30     11:30  
124 Paul Johnson CheckInTime 12:30     12:30
```

Should this be achieved by using pivot command by trying to extract a date from each value? Or should i just create a separate table to pre-fill the dates, yet in this way I would have to do it every month and the report could not be automatically generated

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and pivot is highly vendor specific). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: You can schedule a job (in SQL Agent) that populates this table.. every hour or every day. The problem in my experience is when there are consecutive checkin or checkout records.